# How to disable only error syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've installed the TypeScript package for Sublime Text 3. I want it to still color code syntax, but not red underline and complain about errors. I can't seem to find anything in preferences that would do this for me. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

This is a hack, but it'll do what you want:

- Locate the folder for the TypeScript package. You can do this from within Sublime: Preferences > Browse Packages. On my system this folder is located at `/home/jack/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/TypeScript`
- From within the `TypeScript` folder open the `typescript` folder, then the then `listeners` folder.
- Rename the file `error_list.py` to `error_list_old.py`
- Restart Sublime

This will remove the red underline and the plugin's complaining about errors, but will also remove the entire Error List feature (so the plugin will no longer tell you what it thinks is wrong with your TypeScript code).

If you just want to remove the red underline (but keep the rest) it'll probably be somewhere in that file.

Comment: This worked -- the problem is that I can't copy paste into TypeScript files anymore. I'm guessing this wiped out all the listeners and the copy paste functionality is somehow included in that.

Comment: Shame. You can still paste using right click > paste though, right?

Answer (score 1):

Temp solution: comment lines 26 - 29 (inclusive) in `.../Packges/TypeScript/typescript/commands/error_info.py` and restart sublime. If you are experiencing this with build errors you may also want to disable inline errors in sublime settings `"show_errors_inline": false,`

```
...
if len(error_text) > 0:
  # if PHANTOM_SUPPORT:
  #       template = '<body><style>div.error {{ background-color: brown; padding: 5px; color: white }}</style><div class="error">{0}</div></body>'
  #       display_text = template.format(error_text)
  #       self.view.add_phantom("typescript_error", self.view.sel()[0], display_text, sublime.LAYOUT_BLOCK)
  self.view.set_status("typescript_error", error_text)
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/556#issuecomment-260439591

Note: this disables the large red block but leaves red underlines. Comment the whole file if you do not want those either.